# css file not being downloaded react

Tags: css, reactjs, sass

I have a react application , which I created with Create React App. The app is working fine in development, but in production , the CSS styles are not getting applied. I noticed that, the generated index.html file has the link tag for the bundled stylesheet (main.e72c9739.css), but browser is not downloading the CSS ( there is no network invocation in the dev tools ). The file does get downloaded, when I try manually by entering the address of the URL.

Here is the index.html code

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8"/>
        <base href="/proxy/myusername/services/someserviceid/proxy/8098/"/>
        <link rel="icon" href="favicon.ico"/>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1"/>
        <meta name="theme-color" content="#000000"/>
        <meta name="description" content="Web site created using create-react-app"/>
        <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="logo192.png"/>
        <link rel="manifest" href="manifest.json"/>
        <title>React App</title>
        <script defer="defer" src="/proxy/myusername/services/someserviceid/proxy/8098/static/js/main.01dd9c66.js"></script>
        <link src="/proxy/myusername/services/someserviceid/proxy/8098/static/css/main.e72c9739.css" rel="stylesheet">
    </head>
    <body>
        <noscript>You need to enable JavaScript to run this app.</noscript>
        <div id="root"></div>
        <h1>Hello</h1>
    </body>
</html>
```

One difference I noticed was, in case of development, the css is not explicitly referred via link tag, all the CSS definitions are available in the bundle.js file (along with some code of ***CSS_LOADER_EXPORT*** module).

P.S. The application is deployed in a subpath, and I am using nginx for forwarding the request to react app running on a different port. I also do response modification for appending the base path  of the URL.

Comment: What do you see in the Console or Network tab? No 404?

From what I can tell, its likely about the relative path. What if you don't use ``<base...`` ?

Comment: The generated html has `src` in the stylesheet link tag which may be the issue here. It should have `href` attribute.

Comment: @Marcell there was no network call at all.

Comment: @mathumitha Yeah, this was the problem, I had the reverse proxy code, which was replacing href="static/css" to src="/proxy/myusername/services/someserviceid/proxy/8098/static/css". Please post this as an answer, and I will accept it.